# Plot dynamic json data with d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I would like to make this dynamic js function, where the user can choose the values returned in the json request by constructing a querystring and then plotting the returned json using d3. Something like this:

```
function line_chart(canvas_element, request_url, x_axis, y_axis) {

    var svg = d3.select(canvas_element)
    //...other code to set tup the canvas

    // construct the url
    var url = request_url+"?x_axis="+x_axis+"&y_axis="+y_axis

    d3.json(url, function(error, data){
        if(error) return console.warn(error);

        // scale the range of data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.x_axis;}));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.y_axis})]);

        // other code to draw the svg, axes etc..
   };
};
```

Now if I set `x_axis="tomatoes"` and `y_axis="bananas"` I get json data back like this:

```
[{"tomatoes": 1 , "bananas": 40}, {"tomatoes": 2 , "bananas": 30},
{"tomatoes": 3 , "bananas": 78}]
```

But my code that scales the range of data `d.x_axis` doesn't work because it's looking for a field in the json `x_axis` that doesn't exist. How can I write this so I can get the js to look for whatever field is specified as an input variable to the function?

Comment: Would help if you provided a working example, fiddle maybe ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your accessor functions to be dynamic:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d[x_axis];}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {return d[y_axis];})]);
```

`d[x_axis]` would use the value of x_axis to find the property `d.tomatoes`.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. I'm still new to js so wasn't completely clear on the syntax